# Javascript popup window to be in fron and not steal focus

Tags: javascript

As stated in the Title, i'm trying to figure out if it's possible in Javascript to:

- Open a popup through my parent site with window.open
- Have that popup display in front of the parent
- Not lose **keyboard** focus from the parent window.

So something like the functionality of the popup notification of Windows Messenger for example

Any ideas?

Regards, 
user523842 :P

Comment: Just have hidden DIV with absolute position, show it instead of opening new window. Good example is the link I posted in my answer, just get rid of the CSS in there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use window.open use instead one of many many alternatives aka overlay window/div.

You can use pure JavaScript for this:
http://library.creativecow.net/articles/chaffin_abraham/full-page-overlay.php

Or one of many jQuery solutions as well, just Google for it.

Comment: I think my answer to @annakata's reply is the same for this solution unfortunately

Comment: @user523842 - so I fear it's a dead end. If you have new browser window and you set focus to its parent, the new browser window will disappear. Nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Not afaik. You can't have a focus window underneath a blurred one, but you shouldn't rely on window manipulation anyway because there's a high probability the thing will open in a tab or some other unpredictable client controlled manner. If you want JS dialogs and tight control, use [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) techniques.

Comment: Yes but in my functionality i actually need to open a new popup window...The solutions up to now suggest using overlay windows, which basically are within the parent page. This would not fit my requirements. For example i am restricted to the area of the parent window, and i lose keyboard focus from the parent window... What i want is to keep the parent untouched, and show the information i need in the popup one. More like a toast window functionality...that's what i'm looking for, without stealing focus

Comment: @user - I think you'll have to clarify what your requirements are then, because from an outside standpoint there's no loss of functionality.